# Wordpress website moves around

Tags: html, css, wordpress, header, web

I have a problem when clicking on my website logo, the whole website moves to the right side and back again. It takes one or two clicks but the problem is definitely there.

http://www.du-hd.com

thanks.

Comment: Could not replicate - what browser are you using?

Comment: google chrome..

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the page itself, it's just the redraw of the website that causes this jump effect. Meaning, your content is not optimized and it is bloating the load time.

> ***Reflow is the name of the web browser process for re-calculating the positions and geometries of elements in the document, for the purpose of re-rendering part or all of the document. Because reflow is a user-blocking operation in the browser, it is useful for developers to understand how to improve reflow time and also to understand the effects of various document properties (DOM depth, CSS rule efficiency, different types of style changes) on reflow time. Sometimes reflowing a single element in the document may require reflowing its parent elements and also any elements which follow it.***

Here is a full **[Google Pagespeed analysis](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.du-hd.com%2F&tab=desktop)** of your page.